# Paypal, angular 2 and expressjs server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, paypal

I am new to web development and have put together a decent Angular 2 MEAN web-app that I would like to launch relatively soon. Unfortunately PayPals documentation is such a gigantic Kafkaesque clusterf maze swamp mire that I am lost in and have no clue what I'm doing, I have 30 browser tabs open including code examples and their node sdk/REST. I've tried a few of the different options on offer which involved pasting their scripts to try get a button but nothing happened. Does anyone have a simple guide I can follow and a simple recommendation for integrating paypal payments into MEAN stack? I just need to be able to set payment amounts based on data that is contained in objects I have access to in my front-end, so a simple front-end solution would be nice where user can pay with paypal account or credit card and where I can plug the variable {{event.price}} straight into paypals api and send it off, and verify it somehow.

Thanks

Comment: I am trying to follow this extremely simple guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/  - I pasted the code and the button is not rendering on my html. Why would that be?

Comment: It renders a button in a plain html doc with nothing else but in my angular app it does nothing. Also how do I get a smaller, less ugly button than this giant blob of yellow.

Comment: Also what is with this: "Create a PayPal app to get app credentials. Pass the client ID for the sandbox or live environment in the client option" -- I've tried my sandbox merchant ID, my sandbox email ID, Test API username, signature, anything I could find. There is nothing called a client ID that I can find and I've been looking for hours. Getting this Error: Auth Api invalid sandbox client id.

Comment: Have you tried following these instructions to create a client id? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#create-a-paypal-app

Comment: Also, for the angular side of things, please paste code examples. It's impossible to know what's going wrong without this.

Comment: Ya I followed that exact page and cannot find my client_id and client secret after creating sandbox accounts. I put the paypal code from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/ directly into an angular 2 component and it did nothing, when I put it on a blank html page it loaded an ugly button but because I cant find client ID I cant test it further.